# php function return isset

Tags: php, isset

Please can anyone explain what does this line means in PHP

```
function UserFullName()
{
    return isset($_SESSION['name_of_user'])?$_SESSION['name_of_user']:'';
}
```

Comment: Check out the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 3):

If `$_SESSION['name_of_user']` has something in it, use it; otherwise, use an empty string.

It's using the ternary operator `?:`:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:

Answer (score 1):

if the session variable is set, return the value of the session variable, else return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
if the variables set in the session get the value otherwise return the empty string

Answer (score 0):

the [isset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function returns true if the variable has been set in the script. So this function returns `boolean`, true/false